# Getting value from style setter property in xaml

Tags: wpf

How can I get the value of style setter property in xaml?

For example, I have next style:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="YellowGreen" />
</Style>
```

How can I get the value of Background property from TextBox default style?

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding ???}" />
</Style>
```

I need this because **I haven't access to `TextBox` style**..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you can't modify TextBox style, you could do this work-around (tested, works):

```
<TextBox x:Key="DefaultTextBox" />
<Style TargetType="Button">
  <Setter Property="Background" 
    Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource DefaultTextBox}, Path=Background}" />
</Style>
```

You cannot bind in xaml to style's setter for background.

Answer (score 3):

You should refactor your XAML:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="BackgroundBrush" Color="YellowGreen" />
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BackgroundBrush}" />
</Style>

<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BackgroundBrush}" />
</Style>
```

Bindings hamper performance and are not meant for this kind of action.

Comment: I can't change TextBox style, I have no access to it. So I can't use your approach...