# How to use value from one Style in another Style?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to create a style that makes sure that the ComboBoxes have the same height as the TextBoxes.

I want to achieve this by reusing the height from the default TextBox style.

```
<Style TargetType="ComboBox">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="<Height from default TextBox style>" />
</Style>
```

Am I missing something obvious or is this not possible?

Comment: @Daniel: If you can get the default style using some C#, you could easily write a `StaticResource` that accesses it.

Comment: @PatrickHofman: True and good idea as a last resort. However, if possible, I would like to do this purely in XAML.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: Is this related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16812605/getting-value-from-style-setter-property-in-xaml

Comment: @PatrickHofman: Yes, it is related, but I am not sure it is working  in my case.

Comment: Why not just turn the height into a resource (eg; `<System:Double x:Key="SharedHeight">50</System:Double>`) than load it into both via `<Setter Property="Height" Value="{StaticResource SharedHeight}"/>` since you're naming it on one explicitly anyway?

Comment: @ChrisW. The point is to use the **default** value from the **default** `TextBox` style / template

Comment: The default has no height set, it has a minheight, you could always just bind to actualheight.

Comment: @ChrisW. Yes, that explains my observations. Height is not set, MinHeight is set to 0 and ActualHeight is also 0 in the approach from the link in Patrick's comment

Comment: No in the default wpf style template for textbox there's a minheight set of 20, your ActualHeight will always be 0 until it's rendered and measured for where it displays. However you should be able to slap something on the view that binds to actualheight of another control of any type, it sounds like you guys are over complicating things but maybe I'm reading it wrong.

Comment: @ChrisW. The only thing you are reading wrong is that I don't want to repeat this for every view I have. I want to do this once in a `CommonStyles.xaml` and be done with it. If `MinHeight` of 20 is really set, then at least it is not picked up in my code.

Comment: Soooo why not just do like I said in the first place and set it as a resource so it's global and only needs changed in one spot when you want to change it? Otherwise, you're not going to get that property from anything until it's rendered in which case you'll need to be binding it up on one and have that feed back a double.

Comment: @ChrisW. This question has been created under the assumption that `TextBox` does have a default height. Now that I know that this is not the case, the whole question is more or less invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is as close as I could get:

```
Style defaultStyle = (Style)Application.Current.TryFindResource(typeof(TextBox));

object o = this.GetPropertyValue(defaultStyle, "Height");
```

Where `GetPropertyValue` is:

```
private object GetPropertyValue(Style style, string propertyName)
{
    foreach (Setter s in style.Setters)
    {
        if (s.Property.Name == propertyName)
        {
            return s.Value;
        }
    }

    if (style.BasedOn != null)
    {
        return GetPropertyValue(style.BasedOn, propertyName);
    }

    return null;
}
```

This works, but will fail when the `Style` uses a `Template`. You could walk down that too, but depending on the rendering it will have another height.

In order to use this in XAML, you have to create a static class having a property calling this method.

Comment: As you can see from the continued discussion with Chris below the question itself, the whole thing basically makes no sense ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use BasedOn property.

```
<Style x;Key="MyStyle" TargetType="Control">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="10" />
</Style>

<Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource MyStyle}">
    ...
</Style>

<Style TargetType="ComboBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource MyStyle}">
    ...
</Style>
```

Check more examples on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.basedon(v=vs.110).aspx

You can create style that your default TextBox and ComboBox style will base on.

Comment: Not what I want to use. I want to use the default value from the TextBox style. Whatever that value might be. I don't want to hardcode it. Furthermore, I don't want to base the ComboBox style on the TextBox style because it would inherit not just the height but all other values as well - if it is even possible.

Comment: True, but the types are totally different, so inheritance is not possible.

Comment: How ever can someone upvote this. This isn't even close to an answer.

Comment: @knopo: You clearly don't understand the problem. It is about default styles and getting a property of one style into another, when control types don't match.

Comment: I would say this is a valid answer, its a compromise but only because the OP has asked something that is not possible.

Comment: @BenjaminPaul: It is possible. And OP is fully aware of this possibility.